# select data within a cylindrical space

Tags: filtering

I am facing a problem to select data from a list `{Xn,Yn,Zn}`. Now I need to select data with a criteria `Xn^2+Yn^2=1`. How to write the criteria in select function?

Comment: Try `Select[data, (#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2 == 1) &]`

Comment: Or `Select[data, Total[Most[##]^2] == 1 &]`

Comment: `Select[data, Norm[Most[#]] == 1 &]` is also possible.

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to find points that lie precisely _on_ the cylinder, because of round-off, etc.  If you want the points that lie _inside_ the cylinder, try `Select[data, Element[Most[#], Ball[{0, 0}]] &]`

Comment: I apologise for my lazyness to login. Thanks a lot for the comments